# Checking user input for equality returning error because of "Smart Punctuation"

Tags: javascript, ios, string, reactjs, react-native

I have a React-Native TextInput component that stores user input. I want to check that user input for equality to a string that looks like this:

```
This is a "string."
```

iOS 11, however, automatically italicizes the double quotes *"* so that even if a user types in:

```
This is a "string."
```

The double quotes are not considered the same and the compiler says that the two strings are not equal.

I'm using React-Native version 0.52.0 built with create-react-native-app.

How can I solve/workaround this issue?

EDIT: Here are the curly quotes:

```
Here's a “smart” string.
```

Comment: Convert the smart quotes to dumb quotes once the input is submitted?

Comment: @CertainPerformance how?

Comment: At least I *think* you're referring to smart quotes. Do they look curly rather than straight? Or do they look identical as in your question? Also note that your question's strings aren't identical currently because one has a period, and the other doesn't. copy-pasting, `alert('This is a "string.' === 'This is a "string.');` -> true

Comment: My mistake, I definitely have the period in both. Yeah they look curly rather than straight.

Comment: Can you post the curly quotes in your example so they can be manipulated?

Comment: Added them to my post. @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to convert all smart quotes in the input to dumb quotes before saving the string in your component/variable/database:

```js
const smart = `Here's a “smart” string.`;
const dumb = `Here's a "smart" string.`; // actually dumb
const smartConverted = smart.replace(/[“”]/g, '"');
console.log(smartConverted === dumb);
```

All appearances of “ and ” will be replaced with "

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Quick question though, did you use an alt code for the italicized " or did you just find some online and copy-paste?

Comment: Neither, I just copied from the string you posted directly (that's why I asked for it). (I wasn't 100% sure which characters were being used in your situation)

Comment: Note: The entered text will still (visibly) autocorrect to smart characters (curly quotes, en-dashes) while the user is typing in the TextInput. The resulting (fixed) text will be smart character-free.